# How to join/union two similar tables to do an analysis based on one or more columns?

Tags: sql-server, join, reporting-services

first question here so I'll do my best to make a good post.

I have two data files (excel) which I would like to use for price-volume-mix analysis. These data files have around 50k rows and 20 columns per year.

Example datafile

```
Year  Period Week Article Line    Sales     Weight    Fresh
-     -      -    -       -       -         -         -
2017  1      1    1       Line 1  0         0         Y
..    ..     ..   ..      ..      ..        ..        ..
2017  12     52   99999   Manual  15489,47  10000,20  N

Jaar    float
Periode float
Weeknummer  float
Account nvarchar(255)
Customer    nvarchar(255)
[Account manager]   nvarchar(255)
Market  nvarchar(255)
Land    nvarchar(255)
Verkooprelatie  float
Omschrijving    nvarchar(255)
Artikel float
Omschrijving2   nvarchar(255)
Productgroep    nvarchar(255)
Lijn    nvarchar(255)
Vers    nvarchar(255)
[Eigen productie]   nvarchar(255)
[NNN omzet] decimal(10, 2)
[Contributie marge] decimal(10, 2)
Stuks   decimal(10, 2)
[Consumenten KG]    decimal(10, 2)
```

What I'm trying to do is comparing an forecast/budget with actuals.

I've tried some different joins but I keep running into problems. Example (some names in Dutch) where I'm trying to do a highest level split if it's a fresh or frozen product:

```
Declare @Vers nvarchar = 'J',
@Jaar int = 2018,
@Periode int = 1,
@Weeknummer int = 1;

Select  h.Jaar
   ,NNNHis
   ,KGHis
   ,sum(b.[NNN omzet]) as NNNBud
   ,sum(b.[Consumenten KG]) as KGBud
from 
(
SELECT  Jaar
   ,sum([NNN omzet]) as NNNHis
   ,sum([Consumenten KG]) as KGHis
  FROM [PP_Test].[dbo].[History]

  Where Vers = @Vers
  And Jaar = @Jaar
  And Weeknummer = @Weeknummer
  And Periode = @Periode
  Group by Jaar
) as H

left join [PP_Test].[dbo].[Budget] AS B 
ON H.jaar = B.Jaar


Group by h.jaar, NNNHis, KGHis
```

Declares to enable me to make a report in visual studio where people can select their own periods or weeks.
By using this I get the correct data for my [PP_Test].[dbo].[History] part. For the Budget part I think I'm getting a summation of an summation.

**Problems:**

- I want to create multiple, slightly different reports
- Not sure on which column (how) to join.
- When I join on article I have the problem that I want all articles returned that are in either of the tables (full outer join?) which I can't seem to get to work. This is a requirement for all reports I need to make, if the selection is on Fresh, Article or other column

Comment: is this `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: Would need to see tables structures to know which columns to join on. And you're correct in thinking that using a full outer join will bring back all rows from both tables regardless of matches

Comment: @Squirrel Working in Microsoft SQL Server management studio

Comment: @Ryan Gadson, I've added table design.

Comment: You dont have any primary or foreign keys?

Comment: @Ryan Gadson, no I don't have an unique identifier so forced to join on parts like year or articlenumber

Comment: Thats already a bad idea. I also cant really understand the table names or alias's sorry